# Counting the number of graphs with a certain lower bound on degrees

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, algebraic-graph-theory

I am not that well versed in Graph Theory and would be very grateful if you can direct me to some literature relevant(and helping me to study and hopefully solve)the following problem(if not too difficult!) :

Count the number of reduced graphs on 2n+1 vertices such that the degree of each vertex is at most n.

Thanks a lot,

Ali

Comment: What is a reduced graph?

Comment: No isolated vertex and no vertices with the exact same set of neighbors.